# Регулярные выражения для Python c использование openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал скрипт для сбора логов СХД NetApp:

```
import openpyxl
import subprocess
import os
import datetime
import re

time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
path_to_SMCIPMItool = 'C:/Program Files/StorageManager/client/SMcli.exe'
wb = openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(filename='D:/PythonScritps/NetApp-SN.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

def log_collector():
    while True:
        sanName = input('Enter the name of storage system in 07-06 format: ')
        for row in ws.rows:
            for cell in row:
                if cell.value == sanName:
                    storage_name = str(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=1).value)
                    storage_rack = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=2).value
                    storage_sn_depo = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=3).value
                    storage_sn_manufactur = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=4).value
                    storage_unit = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=5).value
                    print('Serial number of ' + storage_name + ' is ' + storage_sn_depo + ' and serial number of Netapp ' + storage_sn_manufactur)
                    print(storage_name + ' is installed in the rack ' + storage_rack + ' and unite ' + storage_unit)
                    return storage_name

        else:
            cell.value != sanName
            print('not found this storage, try again')
```

В функции идёт обращение к Excel файлу, который имеет в первой колонке имена СХД (например ST13-06-b) и вторая колонка (например 13-06). Когда пользователь через input вводит 13-06, через 2 цикла for проходится по Excel файлу, и если выполняется условие `if cell.vallue == sanName` (вторая колонка Excel файла `(cell.vallue) == 13-06(input)` вытаскивает нужные значения из каждой ячейки. Мне пришлось вводить эту доп колонку с такими названиями(13-06 и т.д), но это немного читерство. Я  бы хотел использовать регулярные выражение для поиска, вводя 13-06, а находил значение в ячейке ST13-06-b.

И вот что получается на выходе скрипта:

```
Enter the name of storage system in 07-06 format: 13-06
Serial number of ST13-06-b is xxxxxx and serial number of Netapp xxxxxxx
ST13-06-b is installed in the rack Стойка xxxxx and unite xxxxx
```

Приведу ниже пример отдельного кода как я пытался играться с регулярными выражениям и вот что получилось.

```
import re
txt = 'ST13-03-b'

look = r"[\w-]+"

all = re.findall(look,txt)
print(all)
```

Подойдёт ли это составленное регулярное выражение и можно ли его использовать при поиске ячеек в Excel и как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: подобные задачи легко решаются при помощи модуля Pandas

Comment: Добавил картинку как выглядит Excel файл и то как работает код

Comment: Если хотите проверенное (протестированное) решение, то создайте [mcve] данных в виде небольшого (5-7 строк) Excel файла и выложите его на любой свободный файлообменник и результат, который вы хотите получить. Врядли кто-то захочет руками вбивать информацию с картинки... PS обо всем этом написано по ссылке из моего первого комментария ;)

Comment: Выложил сюда https://disk.yandex.ru/d/Zsm_evd4qt8PqA Единственное, что в 9 строке кода нужно будет указать путь к файлу Excel на Вашем компьютере.

Comment: Вы хотите искать только по одному столбцу или по всем?

Comment: В примере что я отправил, при вводе, например (02-01), и когда выполняется условие IF, то в переменные записываются все данные из 6 строки всех столбцов, кроме столбца F. Этот метод слегка топорный, так как есть эта читерская колонка F. Я бы хотел от неё избавиться и используя регулярные выражения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html).

Рабочий пример (используем [Single-responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)):

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union, Dict

def parse_log_to_df(filename: Union[str, Path], **kwargs) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.read_excel(filename, **kwargs)

def find_log_entry(
        df: pd.DataFrame,
        san_regex: Union[str, re.Pattern],
        search_col: str = "Name"
) -> Dict[str, str]:
    res = df.loc[df[search_col].str.contains(san_regex)]
    if res.empty:
        return None
    res = res.iloc[0].to_dict()
    return res

def build_report(df: pd.DataFrame, san_regex: Union[str, re.Pattern]) -> str:
    r = find_log_entry(df, san_regex)
    if not r:
         return None
    res = (f'Serial number of {r.get("Name")} is {r.get("SN_DEPO")} '
           f'and serial number of Netapp {r.get("manufactur")}\n'
           f'{r.get("Name")} is installed in the rack {r.get("Rack")}'
           f' and unit {r.get("Unit")}')
    return res
    

df = parse_log_to_df(filename)
san_regex = "06-03"
print(build_report(df, san_regex))
# Serial number of ST06-03-b is xxxxx and serial number of Netapp xxxxx
# ST06-03-b is installed in the rack xxxxx and unit xxxxx

print(build_report(df, san_regex=r"01.*-g$"))
# Serial number of ST01-03-g is xxxxx and serial number of Netapp xxxxx
# ST01-03-g is installed in the rack xxxxx and unit xxxxx
```

Comment: Это работает превосходно, я так-же добавил input для ввода значений, но, пока что мне не совсем понятно как это работает, так как с данным модулем ни разу не работал и не знаю его особенностей. Если Вам не сложно, и когда у Вас будет свободное время, могли бы, пожалуйста, оставить комментарии в коде, чтобы  я мог быстрее разобраться что происходит внутри.

Comment: @Jacob_616, советую начать [отсюда](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html)